# How to guarantee that an NSColor has enough saturation?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nscolor

I need to guarantee that a color has enough saturation.

I made this extension to `NSColor` but my tests give me weird values: `tempColor` always seems to have lots of saturation.

So basically my function always returns self?

Where's my mistake?

I've also tried without converting to `NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace` but that didn't help and the input color can be of different type anyway.

```
extension NSColor {
    func withMinimumSaturation(minimumSaturation: CGFloat) -> NSColor {
        // color could be hue/rgb/other so we convert to rgb
        if var tempColor = self.colorUsingColorSpaceName(NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace) {
            // prepare the values
            var hue: CGFloat = 0.0
            var saturation: CGFloat = 0.0
            var brightness: CGFloat = 0.0
            var alpha: CGFloat = 0.0
            // populate the values
            tempColor.getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &alpha)
            // if color is not enough saturated
            if saturation < minimumSaturation {
                // return same color with more saturation
                return NSColor(calibratedHue: hue, saturation: minimumSaturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: alpha)
            }
        }
        // if detection fails, return same color
        return self
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let source = myColorFromAListOfColors // NSColor
let guaranteed = source.withMinimumSaturation(0.15)
```

*EDIT: actually it works. I've accepted Aaron's answer because it helped me understand the situation (I was comparing the colors with their `redComponents` and they were often similar).*

Comment: When I try with `let source = NSColor.gridColor() ` I get a different color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method seems fine.

For colors with very low saturation, it returns a different color:

[image]

If I increase the minimum saturation from `0.15` to something more significant, like `0.45`, the change is more significant:

[image]

So, this method works as I expect it would. I'm guessing you just need to tweak that `0.15` input to get the results you want.

It may help you to log the old and new saturations for debugging:

```
if saturation < minimumSaturation {
    // return same color with more saturation
    println("New saturation: \(minimumSaturation)")

    return NSColor(calibratedHue: hue, saturation: minimumSaturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: alpha)
} else {
    println("Discarding saturation: \(saturation)")
}
```

Comment: @EricD. I'm not sure about the statistical distribution of color saturation, but I might try a test with 50,000 random colors instead of 100. You might also just test if the colors are equal rather than only looking at `redComponents`.

Comment: I doubt that color space plays into it. Any color should be representable with HSB and opacity values.